# FFmpeg command for crossfading between 5 videos .How to manage setpts=PTS-STARTPTS?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

Here, New in FFmpeg . I am using and testing in console in FFmpeg .

> **I already done with 2 video join with cross fading with this question  :
>    I am doing for 5 videos merging with cross fade  I just done 90%  in  merging 
>   i just need to manage setpts=PTS-STARTPTS Just look into this pls.**

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i 
big_buck.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:4,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[1]; [1:v]trim=1:4,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[2]; 
[2:v]trim=1:4,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[3]; 
[3:v]trim=1:4,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[4]; 
[4:v]trim=1:4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[5]; 
[1][2]overlay,format=yuv420p[12]; [12][3]overlay,format=yuv420p[123]; [4]
[5]overlay,format=yuv420p[45]; [123][45]concat=n=2 [v]" -map [v]  result.mp4
```

****Note that every input video big_buck.mp4 length is 5 sec ****. now see **setpts=PTS-STARTPTS**  in code   How to Manage that in every video Input????

I also see in variuos forums about that but i didnt find!!!
Thank you

Comment: See [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/17504/1871). That shows the method for crossfade. You'll have to concat the overlay output with the third video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i 
big_buck.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(4/TB)[v2]; 
[2:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(8/TB)[v3]; 
[3:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(12/TB)[v4]; 
[4:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(16/TB)[v5]; 
[v1][v2]overlay[v12]; [v12][v3]overlay[v123]; [v123][v4]overlay[v1234]; [v1234][v5]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map [v]  result.mp4
```

The PTS has to be modified so that each new clip starts 1 second before the current combination of clips ends i.e. the 3rd clip should start fading in at 8 seconds, since the combination of the first two clips is 9 seconds (4 seconds of first clip + 1 second transition + 4 seconds of 2nd clip).

You don't need the fade out as the next clip is fading in on top. The concat is only required if you want a cut.

---

With audio crossfades:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i big_buck.mp4 -i 
big_buck.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(4/TB)[v2]; 
[2:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(8/TB)[v3]; 
[3:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(12/TB)[v4]; 
[4:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(16/TB)[v5]; 
[v1][v2]overlay[12]; [12][v3]overlay[123]; [123][v4]overlay[1234]; [1234][v5]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]; \
[1][2]acrossfade=d=1[a12]; [a12][3]acrossfade=d=1[a123]; [a123][4]acrossfade=d=1[a];" \
-map [v] -map [a] result.mp4
```

Comment: There is no cross fading (fade in-fade out between videos )between videos  [checked as output result] .it just  directly merging videos.. can u edit it ... @Mulvya

Comment: Corrected. The timestamps should be changed after the fade. Alternatively, the `st` values for the fades can be changed.

Comment: @Mulvya: When I run your command, there is a small problem. The output video is only 5 seconds instead of 25 second (5 seconds for each video). Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Run your command with `-report` added and link to the logfile generated.

Comment: When I try to use this, I get `No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`. I'm using the second command as-is, substituting my own inputs. What might be happening?

Comment: Remove all whitespace in the filtergraph.

Comment: @Mulvya I'm able to use your video crossfade, but the audio crossfade fails with the same error: `No such filter: ''`. I removed all whitespace in the filter. Do you see any issues with this? 3 videos each 10 secs: `ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -i v3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(9/TB)[v2];[2:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(18/TB)[v3];[v1][v2]overlay[v12];[v12][v3]overlay,format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]acrossfade=d=1[a12];[a12][3]acrossfade=d=1[a];" -map [v] -map [a] result.mp4`

Comment: Remove the last semicolon.

Comment: @Gyan I'm also getting `No such filter: ''`. I've tried removing all whitespace. If I remove the last semicolon, I get `Invalid file index 5 in filtergraph description`. Link to ffmpeg report output: https://pastebin.com/G1UfYMXP

Comment: Replace `[a123][4]acrossfade=d=1[a1234];[a1234][5]acrossfade=d=1[a];` with `[a123][4]acrossfade=d=1[a]`

Comment: @Gyan that worked, thankyou. Please updated the answer.

Comment: Is there no way to simplify those convoluted last lines, or can the overlay/acrossfade filters only take two inputs at a time?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812010/7873775) I have created a convenient Bash script `video_crossfade.sh` to crossfade any number of videos of different duration.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$1"
CMD="ffmpeg"
SIZE=$(find . -iname "$INPUT" | wc -l)

if (( SIZE < 2 ))
then
  echo "2 or more videos are required"
  exit 1
fi

VIDEO=""
OUT=""

i="0"
total_duration="0"
for file in $(find . -iname "$INPUT" | sort)
do
  echo $file
  CMD="$CMD -i $file"

  duration=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of csv=p=0 "$file" | cut -d'.' -f1)

  if [[ "$i" == "0" ]]
  then
    VIDEO="[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];"
  else
    fade_start=$((total_duration-$i))
    VIDEO="${VIDEO}[${i}:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(${fade_start}/TB)[v${i}];"
    if (( i < SIZE-1 ))
    then
      if (( i == 1 ))
      then
        OUT="${OUT}[v0][v1]overlay[outv1];"
      else
        OUT="${OUT}[outv$((i-1))][v${i}]overlay[outv${i}];"
      fi
    else
      if (( SIZE == 2 ))
      then
        OUT="${OUT}[v0][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[outv]"
      else
        OUT="${OUT}[outv$((i-1))][v${i}]overlay,format=yuv420p[outv]"
      fi
    fi
  fi

  total_duration=$((total_duration+duration))

  i=$((i+1))
done

CMD="$CMD -filter_complex \"${VIDEO}${OUT}\" -c:v libx264 -map [outv] crossfade.MP4"

echo "$CMD"

bash -c "$CMD"
```

Example:

```
./video_crossfade.sh '*.MP4'
```

Result:

[image: crossfade any number of images using ffmpeg]

The script takes all videos form by wildcard pattern and uses `ffprobe` to get the video duration.

Comment: This was a great start point for me to get to what I needed. Awesome work. Thank you!

Comment: Eugene I can't thank you enough I was looking for this solution so long. Amazing you just made me super happy very appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width and height in FFmpeg 5 video merge

```
ffmpeg -i 1699476962.mp4 -i 1699860586.mp4 -i 1699752055.mp4 -i 1699860586.mp4 -i 1699752055.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=240:320[v0];[1:v]scale=240:320[v1];[2:v]scale=240:320[v2];[3:v]scale=240:320[v3];[4:v]scale=240:320[v4];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]xstack=inputs=5:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0|0_h0|w0_h0:fill=black[outv];[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a]amix=inputs=5[a]" -map "[outv]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 240x320.mp4
```